# Why does my date difference function spit out incorrect values randomly?

Tags: java, android, math, date, datetime

I'm using the following code to calculate and return the difference between two dates..

```
/**
 * Calculate the absolute difference between two Date without
 * regard for time offsets
 *
 * @param d1 Date one
 * @param d2 Date two
 * @return The fields day, hour, minute, second and millisecond
 */
public static long[] getTimeDifference(Date d1, Date d2) {
    long[] result = new long[7];
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d1);

    long t1 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.setTime(d2);

    long diff = Math.abs(cal.getTimeInMillis() - t1);
    long diffms = diff;


    final int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    final int ONE_MINUTE = ONE_SECOND * 60;
    final int ONE_HOUR = ONE_MINUTE * 60;
    final int ONE_DAY = ONE_HOUR * 24;
    final int ONE_WEEK = ONE_DAY * 7;

    long w = diff / ONE_WEEK;
    diff %= ONE_WEEK;

    long d = diff / ONE_DAY;
    diff %= ONE_DAY;

    long h = diff / ONE_HOUR;
    diff %= ONE_HOUR;

    long m = diff / ONE_MINUTE;
    diff %= ONE_MINUTE;

    long s = diff / ONE_SECOND;

    long ms = diff % ONE_SECOND;

    result[0] = w;
    result[1] = d;
    result[2] = h;
    result[3] = m;
    result[4] = s;
    result[5] = ms;
    result[6] = diffms;

    Log.d("FTT", result[0] + "w, " + result[1] + "d, " + result[2] + "h, " + result[3] + "m, " + result[4] + "s, " + result[5] + "ms, " + result[6] + " diffms, " + "time1: " + t1 +", time2:" + cal.getTimeInMillis() );
    return result;
}
```

The code works perfectly, except every now and then, randomly, it spits out an incorrect value. See the following log, updated every second, created near the end of the above code (w/ Log.d):

```
07-28 17:20:29.225: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 30s, 772ms, 82470772 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898829228
07-28 17:20:30.226: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 29s, 773ms, 82469773 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898830227
07-28 17:20:31.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 28s, 772ms, 82468772 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898831228
07-28 17:20:32.226: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 27s, 773ms, 82467773 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898832227
07-28 17:20:33.226: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 26s, 772ms, 82466772 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898833228
07-28 17:20:34.227: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 7w, 1d, 15h, 57m, 13s, 67ms, 4377433067 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898834229
07-28 17:20:35.223: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 24s, 771ms, 82464771 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898835229
07-28 17:20:36.228: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 23s, 770ms, 82463770 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898836230
07-28 17:20:37.225: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 22s, 769ms, 82462769 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898837231
07-28 17:20:38.229: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 21s, 769ms, 82461769 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898838231
07-28 17:20:39.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 20s, 768ms, 82460768 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898839232
07-28 17:20:40.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 7w, 1d, 15h, 57m, 7s, 65ms, 4377427065 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898840231
07-28 17:20:41.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 18s, 768ms, 82458768 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898841232
07-28 17:20:42.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 17s, 768ms, 82457768 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898842232
07-28 17:20:43.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 16s, 766ms, 82456766 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898843234
07-28 17:20:44.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 15s, 766ms, 82455766 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898844234
07-28 17:20:45.233: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 14s, 765ms, 82454765 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898845235
07-28 17:20:46.234: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 13s, 765ms, 82453765 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898846235
07-28 17:20:47.234: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 7w, 1d, 15h, 57m, 0s, 60ms, 4377420060 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898847236
07-28 17:20:48.235: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 11s, 763ms, 82451763 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898848237
07-28 17:20:49.235: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 10s, 763ms, 82450763 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898849237
07-28 17:20:50.234: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 9s, 764ms, 82449764 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898850236
07-28 17:20:51.234: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 8s, 763ms, 82448763 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898851237
07-28 17:20:52.236: DEBUG/FTT(2095): 0w, 0d, 22h, 54m, 7s, 763ms, 82447763 diffms, time1: 1311981300000, time2:1311898852237
```

As you can see above, three log lines show inconsistent values. It looks to me like time1 and time2 are fine, and the issue occurs when obtaining the difference between the two..

```
long diff = Math.abs(cal.getTimeInMillis() - t1);
```

Any ideas as to why this could be happening? I've wracked my brain and can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to discover why this is?

Comment: Without knowing the inputs (i.e. `d1` and `d2`), no one can answer your question.  It looks like the problem lies outside of this function however.

Comment: Regarding line 07-28 17:20:34.227: DEBUG/FTT(2095): if I understand correctly, then diffms=abs(time1-time2)=1311981300000-1311898834229=82465771!=4377433067.  Of course your other values would be screwed up as well.

Comment: You could, of course, extract the milliseconds from your `Date` objects, directly - no need to involve `Calendar`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using exactly the same code and calling it once per second with the current date/time and a date/time set to 23 hours from the start of execution. Can you give more detail about the exact conditions that cause it?

Comment: @Oli. yes.. it occurs at the long diff assignment.

Comment: @shinkou.. d1 and d2 are just dates, their ms values are in the log.

Comment: @ryan.. i wish i could.. it appear to be random, but seems to occur after running for several minutes. i have a label flash red to alert me of when it happens so i can check logcat straight away.

Comment: Hard to see what the problem is -- but you should try two things. Use date.getTime() directly instead of creating a calendar. If not, at least create two separate calendar instances for the two dates instead of reusing the same one.

Comment: @kefsco I'd suggest you try logging the two inputs directly and see if they always behave what they're supposed to be.

Comment: This is getting old, but what happens to the dates outside that method? This could be explained by unsafe concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs of Math.abs: "Note that if the argument is equal to the value of Long.MIN_VALUE, the most negative representable long value, the result is that same value, which is negative."

If the result of (cal.getTimeInMillis() - t1) is Long.MIN_VALUE you'll use negative values in your modulo operations. Afaik, doing that can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: But i'm not even coming close to Long.MIN_VALUE -9223372036854775808L..  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE